# Count and inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql

Look at this sql request:

```
select distinct erp.users.id 
from erp.users
inner join prod.referral_order_delivered
on erp.users.id= prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id::uuid
inner join erp.orders 
on erp.orders."userId"::uuid= erp.users.id
where
    "paidAt"::date >= '2016-06-07'
    and "paidAt"::date <= '2017-07-07'
```

Let’s say I get a result like this one:

```
id 
2
1
4
5
```

Now I wanna count how many times the value of these ids appear as value of the column userId in the table erp.orders

For example, if I have erp.orders.userId which is:

```
userId
2
2
1
4
4
5
5
5
```

I want the request that is gonna return this:

```
id  number_of_id
2   2
1   1
4   2
5   3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is neither MySQL nor SQL Server, so I removed those tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: yes sorry it's postgresql. Can you go into more details with group by gordon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `count()` function and a `group by` clause. It'll look something like:

```
select 
  erp.users.id
  , count(1)
from 
  erp.users
  inner join prod.referral_order_delivered
    on erp.users.id = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id::uuid
  inner join erp.orders 
    on erp.orders."userId"::uuid = erp.users.id
where
    "paidAt"::date     >= '2016-06-07'
    and "paidAt"::date <= '2017-07-07'
group by
    erp.users.id
```

Comment: @MerwaneHamadi: Don't forget to accept if it adequately answered your question!